# How can I transfer an information from child component to parent component React.js with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to develop a front end for the pokemon API. I easily developed the main page with a pokemon cards. I also add a button for each card to click and link to individual pokemon page. However, I need to get the information from the clicked pokemon card to connect the related pokemon API. I have written the callback function, which takes the information from the clicked pokemon card. However, when I want to deliver this to a component the information vanishes. I have put the demo of the code at codesandbox. Basically, how can I deliver the information that I want from child to child while I use react router?

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-elbakyan-f7thl

Comment: Please update your question to include a relevant [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the code you've an issue with.

Comment: While you're working on an example, consider Redux.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this problem but your biggest mistake is **navigating with an `<a>` element**.  If you use a `Link` from `react-router-dom` then the state of your `App` component will be preserved.  When you use an `<a>` you are causing a total refresh of the page and losing your state.

I changed this section of your `PokeBox` component:

```
<a
   className="btn btn-info"
   href={`/${poke.name}`}
   onClick={() => {
       onPokeDetail(poke);
   }}
>
```

to

```
<Link
    className="btn btn-info"
    to={`/${poke.name}`}
    onClick={() => {
        onPokeDetail(poke);
    }}
>
```

and added the appropriate import statement:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

Now I am seeing the Pokemon name and url getting logged to the console by the `PokeDetail` component.

Comment: It is the direct solution for my problem thank you, I was also trying the carry information via Url. But your solution  looks much more clear. Cheers